# How to access and present the visible content of an opened tab within a safari extension?

Tags: javascript, tabs, safari, browser, safari-extension

While developing my Safari Extension, I want to access the captured screenshot of an opened tab in the active browser window. As of the [SafariBrowserTab Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/SBrowserTabClassReference/SafariBrowserTab.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009793) it should be possible to access the [visible content](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/SBrowserTabClassReference/SafariBrowserTab.html#//apple_ref/javascript/instm/SafariBrowserTab/visibleContentsAsDataURL). How can I use this to show the visible content within an image tag on my content page of the safari extension?

Currently I'm able to show all opened tabs with its urls and titles. But it is not possible  to get the visible content.

It would be nice if someone can help me with my problem.

Answer (score 3):

In your global page, use `visibleContentsAsDataURL` with a callback function to get the image data of the screenshot. Then send it to your content page similarly to how you are sending titles and URLs.

For example:

### global.js

```
safari.application.addEventListener('command', performCommand, false);

// Perform e.g. when toolbar button is clicked
function performCommand(event) {
    if (event.command === 'captureTab') {
        safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.visibleContentsAsDataURL(function(imgdata){
            //console.log(imgdata);
            safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.page.dispatchMessage('imgData', imgdata);
        });
    }
}
```

### injected.js

```
safari.self.addEventListener('message', handleMessage, false);

// Receive a message from the global page
function handleMessage(msg) {
    if (msg.name === 'imgData') {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = msg.message;
        document.body.appendChild(img);
    }
}
```